# How do I make this accessory work like a cloth with bones?

Tags: bones, physics

I'm trying not to have to go through the headache of animating the cloth on each part it's seen.
Is there any good way to make this process faster with good cloth-like results?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8dvW.jpg

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a game model, or I assume it is. In game, each different position for the cloth would be animated then baked. The game isn't going to use live cloth simulations or even be rigged with bones, it'll just have a few different baked shapes it just blends between.

You can do this the same way- you would sculpt/animate a few different cloth shapes and bake them. (Shape keys work well for this.) If you don't, you'll need dozens of bones to get "good cloth-like results"- i.e., wrinkles, you'll have to have one bone per wrinkle (that's an oversimplification, but it works for illustration purposes.) This is what cloth simulation is for, to avoid the immense complexity that you would have to create to rig cloth with bones. Both rigging with bones and cloth simulation will SIGNIFICANTLY slow down your animations, (assuming you're using enough bones for realistic cloth), so that's probably a no-go.

One way or another, you're going to have to "animate the cloth on each part it's seen." Just make sure you bake those animations, since they'll never run in real-time or anywhere near it.

Comment: Ah ok. How do game physics usually work? The cloth usually moves very fluently with the unpredictable movements of your character. So I would think it's a live simulation. (Second question) Are my only choices are, to create a simulation with a bones that'll tremendously slow down my animation, or animate it all by hand?

Comment: There's an excellent article about tricks game developers use to avoid cloth simulations, and the reasons they do so. You should check it out: https://80.lv/articles/cloth-simulation-for-games-difficulties-and-current-solutions/

Comment: Thanks. Idk if you read my second question, it was edited. "Are my only choices are, to create a simulation with bones that'll tremendously slow down my animation, or animate it all by hand?"

Comment: Those are your two *best* options for sure. You could use a cloth simulation (also very slow), or you could try one of the workarounds game developers use sometimes. That article specifically mentioned two- a low poly A frame, or blending normal maps. You can probably find more on Google. TLDR: your "normal" options are those two, but there are hacky/specialized workarounds some games use

Comment: I've also found other articles where developers script specific cloth functionality for specific pieces of cloth, and it's not uncommon for developers to do that (write a highly specific cloth system that performs super well with very specific parameters) Writing your own cloth system is probably out of your scope, so I'd recommend sculpting by hand and baking those to shapekeys

Comment: Okayy. Thanks for the help!